# Active Directory Group Performance

Tags: asp.net, windows, active-directory

For an Active Directory group with a large number of users, which option would provide better performance?

**Option 1:** Adding all users directly into the Active Directory group (No nested groups)

**Option 2:** Adding all users into sub groups, and then adding the sub groups into the Active Directory group.

**Context:** I have an internal websites that uses two Active Directory groups for authentication.

Which option would provide the fastest performance when dealing with approximately ~1000 users. Due to security restrictions I cannot cache the authentication information, so it is checked anytime the user refreshes the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your goal is to increase performance of verifying if a user is a member of a group, then dealing with one group is better then expand membership in case of nested groups (even on the server side). 1000 users is a pretty small environment, so everything should work fine. You can check if a group contains user via member attribute or a user belongs to a group via memberOf attribute and see which way is faster

Comment: @oldovets Yes, after some re-testing I re-wrote the code to not perform the recursive searching (for 1000 users directly in the AD group) and it seems that the performance is much better. So I guess the unnecessary recursive searching is what was slowing it down so much! If you wanna put your comment as answer i'd be happy to upvote.